# A function inside javascript if condition is not getting called

Tags: javascript

I am new to Js and trying to develop program which can move object in zig zag format across canvas, i wrote this function but it not getting called when i run program. If anyone can check out my code it would be really helpful, thanks also like to mention that all previous functions in code are working fine but this specific function is not getting called program run until If condition but skip the function part. Also i am not looking to work with Jquery or CSS right now

```
if (rightPos) {
  function myInterval3() {
    console.log('hello');
    var eLeftPos1 = e.offsetLeft;
    //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
    e.style.left = (eLeftPos1 + s) + 'px';
    //console.log(e.style.left);
  }
}
```

---

```
var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var s = 1;



function myInterval() {
  var eLeftPos = e.offsetLeft;
  //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
  e.style.left = (eLeftPos + s) + 'px';
  //console.log(e.style.left);

  leftPos = (eLeftPos + s) >= 300

  if (leftPos) {
    function myInterval1() {
      console.log(leftPos)
      var eTopPos = e.offsetTop;
      //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
      e.style.top = (eTopPos + s) + 'px';

      //console.log(e.style.top);

      topPos = (eTopPos + s) >= 100

      if (topPos) {
        clearInterval(internal1)
      }

      if (topPos) {
        function myInterval2() {
          var eRightPos = e.offsetLeft;
          //console.log(eRightPos)
          e.style.left = (eRightPos - 9) + 'px'
          /*console.log(e.style.left)*/

          rightPos = (eRightPos - 9) <= 20

          if (rightPos) {
            clearInterval(interal2)
          }
        }
        var interal2 = setInterval(myInterval2, 10)

      }

    }
    var internal1 = setInterval(myInterval1, 100);

    if (rightPos) {
      function myInterval3() {
        console.log('hello');
        var eLeftPos1 = e.offsetLeft;
        //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
        e.style.left = (eLeftPos1 + s) + 'px';
        //console.log(e.style.left);
      }
    }

  }

  if ((eLeftPos + s) >= 300) {
    clearInterval(internal)
  }
}
var internal = setInterval(myInterval, 100);
```

Comment: can you make the code somewhat legible - with non-random indentation? by the way, you should never declare a function inside a conditional like that

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that anyone can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Where are you calling the function? You have only defined your function in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a function named `myInterval3`, but you're not calling it. When you write

```js
function myInterval3() { ... }
```

That defines a function named `myInterval3`, but that's all that it does. To actually have the code inside the function run, you need to call it.

```js
myInterval3()
```

To have the function called on a repeating interval, use `setInterval` (like you have for your other functions:

```js
setInterval(myInterval3, 100)
```